# iptables issue: libipt_DPORT.so not found

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to set up a proxy server on an Ubuntu Box, but my linux-fu is pretty weak and I'm stymied with an iptables issue.

I'm trying to execute this command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp -m –dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

The error I get back is this:

```
iptables v1.4.4: Couldn't load match `-dport':/lib/xtables/libipt_-dport.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

There is, in fact, no file with that name.

iptables was not installed on my machine, I did:

```
apt-get install iptables
```

to install it. Finally, here's my distro info:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04 LTS"
```

Any idea what's going on? If this is an obvious question, please point me to the relevant documentation; I'm kinda lost on even where to look, and Googling pulls up nothing.

Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: Are you sure you typed the command correctly as posted here? The `dport` option should be written as `--dport`.

Comment: You're right, I was missing the dash. However, I still get an error. I've updated my error message above.

Comment: I see that this error can happen when you write the command with missing tcp after `-m`.

Comment: Hi Khaled, I'm not sure I follow. Can you perhaps paste the command with tcp in the right place? I don't really follow.

Comment: I think you issued the command as: `iptables -A INPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp -m -dport 443 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact command I'm using, and it's producing the above error. What should the command be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enter the command as follows:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Pay attention to the protocol name after `-m` and double dash before `dport`. You can also remove `-m tcp` from the above command as it is useless in your command.